# how can i display users who liked the post in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

list of users who liked the post are shows like

john,smith, jack, george ....

I am trying to show this like 
john,smith and 10 others

if we click on 10 others, show their name

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: provide some code and working model.

Comment: Please read the help section on how to ask a question here and what kind of questions are on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code for showing john,smith and 10 others
Let's say you have those names in an array called $names:

```
$names = array('Daan', 'John', 'Jack', 'George');
$numberOfNames = count($names);

if($numberOfNames <= 2) {
   foreach($names as $name) {
     echo $name;
   }
} else { 
   $count = 0;
   foreach($names as $name) {
      if($count == 2) {
         echo "and " .$numberOfNames - 2. "others";
      } else {
         echo $name;
      }
      $count++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check some sample PHP code i wrote to develop this sort of a functionality. This sort of works like Facebook Likes:

For 1 like: Either You like This or "This Person" Likes this.

For 2 Likes: Either "You and This Person like this" or "This person and This person likes this"

For 3 Likes: Either "You, This Person and This person Like this" or "This Person, This Person and This Person like this"

For More than 3 likes: "You, This Person and  Others like this" or "This Person, This Person and  others like this"

```
$query="select likes from feed where id='".$id."'";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

$likes=$row['likes'];

$display="";

if($likes == NULL || $likes=="")
{
    $display="No one likes this";
}
else
{
    $array=explode(",",$likes);

    $count=count($array);

    if($count==1)
    {
        if($array[0]==CURRENTLY LOGGED IN ID)
        {
            $display="You like this";
        }
        else
        {
            $name=getName($array[0]);
            $display='<a href="profileview.php?id='.$array[0].'">'.$name.'</a> likes this';
        }
    }
    elseif($count==2)
    {
        if(in_array('CURRENTLY LOGGED IN ID',$array))
        {
            $name="";
            if($array[0]=='CURRENTLY LOGGED IN ID')
            {
                $name=getName($array[1]);
                $display='You and '.'<a href="profileview.php?id='.$array[1].'">'.$name.'</a> like this';
            }
            elseif($array[1]=='CURRENTLY LOGGED IN ID')
            {
                $name=getName($array[0]);
                $display='You and '.'<a href="profileview.php?id='.$array[0].'">'.$name.'</a> like this';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $name1=getName($array[0]);
            $name2=getName($array[1]);
            $display='<a href="profileview.php?id='.$array[0].'">'.$name1.'</a> and <a href="profileview.php?id='.$array[1].'">'.$name2.'</a> like this';
        }
    }
    elseif($count==3)
    {
        if(in_array('CURRENTLY LOGGED IN ID',$array))
        {
            $name1="";
            $name2="";
            if($array[0]=='CURRENTLY LOGGED IN ID')
            {
                $name1=getName($array[1]);
                $name2=getName($array[2]);
                $display='You,'.'<a href="profileview.php?id='.$array[1].'">'.$name1.'</a> and '.'<a href="profileview.php?id='.$array[2].'">'.$name2.'</a> like this';
            }
            elseif($array[1]=='CURRENTLY LOGGED IN ID')
            {
                $name1=getName($array[0]);
                $name2=getName($array[2]);
                $display='You,'.'<a href="profileview.php?id='.$array[0].'">'.$name1.'</a> and '.'<a href="profileview.php?id='.$array[2].'">'.$name2.'</a> like this';
            }
            elseif($array[2]=='CURRENTLY LOGGED IN ID')
            {
                $name1=getName($array[0]);
                $name2=getName($array[1]);
                $display='You,'.'<a href="profileview.php?id='.$array[0].'">'.$name1.'</a> and '.'<a href="profileview.php?id='.$array[1].'">'.$name2.'</a> like this';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $name1=getName($array[0]);
            $name2=getName($array[1]);
            $name3=getName($array[2]);

        $display='<a href="profileview.php?id='.$array[0].'">'.$name1.'</a>,'.'<a href="profileview.php?id='.$array[1].'">'.$name2.'</a> and '.'<a href="profileview.php?id='.$array[2].'">'.$name3.'</a> like this';
        }
    }
    elseif($count>3)
    {
        if(in_array($userid,$array))
        {
            $name="";

            $left=count($array)-2;

            if($array[0]=='CURRENTLY LOGGED IN ID')
            {
                $name=getName($array[1]);
                $display='You,'.'<a href="profileview.php?id='.$array[1].'">'.$name.'</a>'.' and '.$left.' other people like this'; 
            }
            else
            {
                $name=getName($array[0]);
                $display='You,'.'<a href="profileview.php?id='.$array[0].'">'.$name.'</a>'.' and '.$left.' other people like this';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $name1=getName($array[0]);
            $name2=getName($array[1]);

            $left=count($array)-2;

        $display='<a href="profileview.php?id='.$array[0].'">'.$name1.'</a>, '.'<a href="profileview.php?id='.$array[1].'">'.$name2.'</a>,'.' and '.$left.' other people like this';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He is using CodeIgniter...

Comment: Okay. This is just sample code of how we could approach it.